# firebase: Connect to a custom domain that has no SSL certificate?

Tags: firebase, ssl

My domain has no SSL certificate, I want to connect the domain to my firebase app. It is possible or do I have to buy a certificate first to do so? If yes, my host offers a ssl certificate without validation of the owner.. is this good enough?

Comment: what features of firebase your app is using ?

Comment: realtime database, storage, authentification

Comment: it should fine event with no ssl certificate

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Firebase Hosting can connect to your own custom domains, like https://example.com or https://myrealtimeapp.example.com. Firebase Hosting provisions an SSL certificate for your domain and serves your content over a global CDN.

You don't have to provide your own SSL